# Adding and multiplying AMPSCRIPT

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm looking to add one number (320019) to a sum the day of the month times another number 40. Any help with number outputting amscript in emails would be very much appreciated!

```
%%[ VAR @currentSystemTime, @FIGUREA, @FIGUREB, @DatePart 
SET @currentSystemTime=NOW() 
Set @FIGUREB =Mulitiply(@DatePart"a",40) 
Set @FIGUREA ="320019" ]%%

%%=Add(@FIGUREA,@FIGUREB)=%%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FigureB's Multiply function is incorrect syntax and I was not sure what you were looking to do with the @DatePart variable...

Try this:

```
%%[
SET @Day = DATEPART(Now(), "D")
SET @FirgureA = 320019
SET @FigureB = MULTIPLY(@Day, 40)

SET @Final = ADD(@FigureA, @FigureB)
]%%

%%=v(@Final)=%%
```

I would be careful though basing a number on a date as on the VAWP and any webpage use, the number will change based on when it was loaded, not when it was sent (AMPScript will be rerun).

Comment: Glad to have helped! If you feel my response answers your question, please click the checkmark next to it to make sure anyone else looking at the question knows it has been solved.